# How do I insert user_id with ManyToOne relationship in symfony?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

Really new with symfony, coming from yii.

I can't insert user_id into another table with a ManyToOne relationship. 
When I get entity of the table that I want to insert of the id, I used:
`$en->setUser($user_id);`

The outcome is:
`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null`

but when I do `var_dump($user_id);` there is an id. 
So how can I insert user_id with a many to one relationship?

**[update]**
*TableUser Entity*

```
<?php
namespace User\Bundle\RegisterBundle\Entity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="user_id", columns={"user_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $userId;

    public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->userId;
    }
}
?>
```

*TableSomeModel Entity* that has ManytoOne relationship with user_id

```
<?php
namespace \Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * SomeModel
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="SomeModel", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="user_id", columns={"user_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class SomeModel
{
    /**
     * @var \User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     * })
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \Entity\User $user
     * @return App
     */
    public function setUser(\Entity\User $user)
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \Entity\User 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

**In the controller**

```
$en = new SomeModel();
var_dump($user_id); //not null
$en->setUser($user_id); //always null;
```

Comment: Show the two related entities please

Comment: Could you please share the code wherein you have declared the relations(yml file or the annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have defined the relation properly. If you are using yml configuration files for defining entities, 
many to one relations are configured as given below.

```
manyToOne:
user:
  targetEntity: Your\NameSpace\Entity\User
  joinColumn:
    name: user_id
    referencedColumnName: id
```

If you are using annotation to define the relation,

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Your\NameSpace\Entity\User")
 * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $user;
```

And the setUser method in your entity

```
 /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param Blsk\CoreBundle\Entity\User $user
     */
    public function setUser(Your\NameSpace\Entity\User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
```

**EDIT**
In your code, `setUser` method is not setting the user but returning the user.

Comment: oh thanks. I think im missing the first part. Is this under config.yml? (sorry for the noob question). Must it be config every single time there's a many to one (many) relationship?

Comment: Since you are using annotations, that is not required. I posted the answer before you posted your code. Please discard the first part. You can use **either** annotations or yml files to specify the model structure and relations. No need to use both.

Answer (score 4):

```
$en->setUser($User); // $User is object
```

OR

```
$en->setUser($em->getReference('User\Bundle\RegisterBundle\Entity\User', $user_id)); // $user_id is integer, $em is EntityManager
```